# Error building package in R 3.1.2 w/ multiple third party DLL's

Tags: r, dll, shiny

A colleague ported more than a thousand S functions and Fortran subroutines to R. The native R functions are contained in 5 .RData files and the Fortran subroutines are contained in 2 .dll files.

I can load these files into the R workspace using

```
for (i in 1:5){    load(list.files()[grep("RData",strsplit(list.files(),"\\W+"))][i]) } 
for (i in 1:2){dyn.load(list.files()[grep("dll"  ,strsplit(list.files(),"\\W+"))][i]) }
```

After some troubleshooting I know that the relationships between R code and the Fortran subroutines were already well established by the original author.

Now I want to create a package from these files because I'm unable to deploy my ioslides_presentations with these dll files since shinyapps.io is built with Linux.  This is my first attempt at creating an R package, I don't intend to publish it to the CRAN, I'm only interested in generating a local zip file that I and my students can load.

MY PROCESS

After loading the functions in the workspace using the above code, I ran `package.skeleton` and `system("R CMD build package")` which successfully created "package_1.0.tar.gz".  After completing the DESCRIPTION file, I put the .dll files I the `src` sub-directory and included `useDynLib(DLL1), useDynLib(DLL2)` in the NAMESPACE file.

However, when I run `system("R CMD INSTALL build package_1.0.tar.gz")` I get the following error:

Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL 'package.dll' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: loading failed
Execution halted

I've spent a great deal of time reading through "Writing R Extensions", "Advanced R" by Hadley Wickham, and the devtools documentation.  Even so, I'm having difficulty deciphering `useDynLib`, `.onLoad`, `Export`, `Call`, and `Makevars` and which should be used for pre-compiled Fortran code.

I really don't want to parse through all of these functions to find which require export rules if I don't have to. I'd appreciate any help getting these .dll files loaded so I can finish creating this package

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: You `R CMD build ./` a directory with a DESCRIPTION file; then you `R CMD install package.tar.gz`

Comment: This results in the same error I originally desribed

Comment: I am likely mistaken here (I have been using `devtools` and developing mostly on windows), but does it help to put the libraries within `./src-i386/` or a similar architecture-specific directory?

Comment: @r2evans I doubt that will help. I have never heard of `src-i386` before.

Comment: @JasonFreels It seems you still do not know the basic workflow of building an R package (you are not supposed to manually create .dll files and use them; all you need is just `R CMD build` and `R CMD INSTALL`). And "Advanced R" is the wrong book to read. Read "R Packages" instead: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz

Comment: @Yihui, it's likely a side-effect of using `Rcpp`. It appears to copy the files from `./src/` into `./src-i386/` and `./src-x64/` and compile them for the 32- and 64-bit libraries, respectively. I don't have external libraries at the moment to test, so it was just a guess.

Comment: @r2evans Oh okay. I rarely use Rcpp myself, so I have no idea, and you could be right.

Comment: @Yihui I don't dispute that I have much to learn on developing packages. However, the problem here is that I'm getting these files 10 years after the fact. If the answer is that I need to extract an unknown number of Fortran subroutines from these .dll files and list each of them in the NAMESPACE, I may have to rethink my strategy.  You are also correct on the book, I have been using R packages, but I initially linked to it from the "Advanced R" page.